# Java - @Before and @test annotation

Tags: java, testing, annotations, junit4

I am very new to Java programming. I have a unit test file to be run. It has annotations of `@Before` and `@Test`. I have tried to understand these concepts using available online resources.

When I am debugging my UnitTest.java file, only the `@Before` part gets executed. It does not reach `@Test` and the program fails saying:

```
NativeMethodAccessorImpl.Object(....) not available.
```

This does not happen when I *run* the unit tests (as opposed to *debugging* the unit tests).
How do I go about solving this?

Comment: You see *where* it's failing, then try to figure out *why*. As we can't see your code, there's little else we can offer.

Comment: Putting a snapshot from the code or may be the stacktrace can help

Comment: Did you get the case right when you typed `@test` into your question? In the file, is "test" spelled lower case or is it spelled `Test`?

Comment: I think the compiler will complain if the op use lower case and no other @test definition.

Comment: @user802421: True. I am just trying to ensure that there is no other annotation in the project named `test`.

Comment: @Samhitha, what unit testing library are you using? JUnit or TestNG?

Comment: When I run the test.java file It works!
 But when i try to debug, the breakpoints do not work for for @test methods.

Comment: @Samhitha: You should follow Muhammad's recommendation and edit your question to include the full stack trace of the error. It would help us understand the error better than the snippet you included. By the way, is that snippet an *exact* copy of the error you received? It looks strange.

Answer (score 5):

The `@Before` and `@Test` annotations are used to define unit tests for the Java JUnit testing framework.  See http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/cookbook/cookbook.htm for an introduction and examples of JUnit unit testing using these annotations.

Your problem is that your have mis-spelled the `@Test` annotation as `@test`.

Comment: That was a typo in the posted question... 
In the code it is @Test.
Thanks for the link...I will check that out.